# Can GeoServer be hosted in Azure?

Tags: geoserver, installation, azure

Can GeoServer be hosted in Azure?

I presume that it would be as a virtual machine, because it needs a JRE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure provides ready built Ubuntu boxes (and yes, that means virtual machines), so it should be no problem having GeoServer (or MapServer) installed and working.
There used to be an [OpenGeo image for AWS](http://boundlessgeo.com/2010/09/opengeo-suite-community-edition-on-amazon-web-services/), I don't know if that's still out there but it's also a good option since it comes preconfigured.

Comment: Ah ha ... yeap, found the Azure OpenGeo image ... https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/marketplace/partners/boundlessgeo/opengeosuite/